# List of Ubuntu Mirror with x86 and armhf

Tags: mirrors

is there any mirror of Ubuntu packages with amd64 i586 AND armhf packages? All combined in one  repository.

I Need this as I use the open Build service as a local instamnce and cant create packages as the packages dh-systemd is not available on port.ubunut.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each mirror admin decides which architectures they will mirror.

There are two consolidated lists of mirrors ([mirrors.ubuntu.com](http://mirrors.ubuntu.com) and the [Launchpad Archive Mirrors](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors)), but neither tracks architectures.